# Moving Steam (installed w/ Wine) to another HDD without reinstalling games

Tags: wine, steam

Is there any way to move Steam and all of my Steam games to another hard drive without having to re-installing everything? I would prefer to keep Wine on the original drive, if possible. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and the most recent stable release of Wine.

Answer (score 1):

Find the folder that steam saves games into, MOVE it to your second drive. Then link the new directory to where the old was
ln -s /mount/drive/games /home/user/.wine/path/to/games

Comment: btw congrats on apparently getting it to work, I tried playing portal through wine, worked OK until I shot a portal.

Comment: Tried it, but got this: ryan@ryan-desktop:~$ ln -s /media/Hitachi/Steam /home/ryan/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Steam
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Theres a space in program files, you need quotes. ln -s /media/Hitachi/Steam "/home/ryan/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Steam"

Comment: btw welcome to askUbuntu, when someone has fully answered your question check the check mark next to their answer.